# Avoiding deadlock within AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange notification callback

Tags: swift, concurrency, deadlock, avaudioengine

I have a Swift class that contains an instance of AVAudioEngine and I and making use of the AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange notification like so:

```
class Demonstration : NSObject {
    
    var engine:AVAudioEngine? = AVAudioEngine()
    
    // ...
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        // ...
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.handleEngineConfigChange(_:)),
                                               name: .AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange,
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func handleEngineConfigChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        // what can I wrap this code with in order to make it not dangerous?
        // DispatchQueue.main.sync?
        engine = nil
        
    }
    
}
```

In the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1389078-avaudioengineconfigurationchange) it says:

> Don’t deallocate the engine from within the client’s notification
> handler. The callback happens on an internal dispatch queue and can
> deadlock while trying to tear down the engine synchronously.

I don't even really know what they mean by deallocate -- if it means there's some method like engine.reset() or engine.stop()... or whether it means setting the engine to nil... or if it only applies to objective C... which I don't know.

At any rate, I would just like to know how to set up the method so that in the future I don't have to worry about breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

You can move this to the next iteration of the runloop by using `DispatchQueue.async` (not sync) to whatever queue you are managing your engine on (probably the main queue). The important thing is that you apply the changes *after* returning from this callback.

Comment: Thanks!  Would it be possible to include an editted version of my code to show right vs wrong way?